# Arithmetic operator on negative numbers in Swift

Tags: swift, math, int

I am learning some game dev with Swift and so I want to know when a node is further away in the Z axis. My calc is:

```
if zPositionOfBowlingBall > -7 { 
  // Do something here
}
```

So if the position is greater than -7 so -8 as an example execute the block of code. This never gets called. I am guessing this is how the signed int works. If someone could explain that would be really helpful to understand and what the correct syntax would be.

UPDATE complete code here

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        bowlingBall.removeBowlingBallWhenZPositionIsReached()
    }
}

func removeBowlingBallWhenZPositionIsReached() {
        guard let bowlingBallNode = bowlingBallNode else {return}
        let bowlingBallPosition = bowlingBallNode.presentation.worldPosition
        let zPositionOfBowlingBall = Int(bowlingBallPosition.z)
        if zPositionOfBowlingBall > -7 {
            performFadeOutOnBowlingBallWith(duration: 2.0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this. Basically in this block I remove a node. But it removes it straight away I only want to remove it when the node is past -7 I can do == -7 but this is not what I want.

Comment: your comment didn't clarify much

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Sorry about that. Didn't think it would make a difference to the question

Comment: post more related code

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Updated code above. In short when the ball reaches further away than -7 in the z axis remove it. Or in my case I fade it out.

Comment: Be more specific of what is happening and what you wish was happening.

Comment: I think it's overly obvious what I want now. But thanks for helping all the same.

Comment: The function name speaks for itself removeBowlingBallWhenZPositionIsReached()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-8 is less than -7, therefore your code should be:

```swift
if zPositionOfBowlingBall < -7 { 
  // Do something here
}
```

if you want the value to be greater than 7 regardless of the sign you can use absolute value.

`abs(<#value#>)`

Comment: Thank you please see my comments above maybe I didn't explain what I wanted clearly.

Comment: I’ve accepted as correct as you are right what was confusing me was that my ball is removed right away as the delegate function is called 60fps so I need an extra check to perform.